# Transaction rollback on CannotAcquireLockException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-jdbc

I am using spring AOP + hibernate transaction manager for managing my transactions. In my production environment, I am getting CannotAcquireLockException due to some jobs running parallelly.

I have a header table and an item, when I try to insert into header table, items are inserted automatically by hibernate cascade functionality. So when I am running into CannotAcquireLockException on item table, the only header is getting saved and not the item, even though they are in the same transaction.

unfortunately, I am not supposed to share my code, but please let me know if you need any details.

When I am getting any other exception the transaction is getting rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

This is a definite deadlock situation. This is more related to DB  error than a hibernate/Spring problem with your classes. I faced similar situation where a thread was doing Select and another thread was trying to Insert/Update the same row. Some quick solutions.

1. Use Select.. For Update sql query : This normally  acquires the lock on particular index until operation is done.
2. On DB side : Creating indexes also help.

Hope this helps. More details [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-deadlocks.html)

Comment: Hey Ankit, Thanks for quick reply, now the main issue for me is why the transaction is not getting rolled back. Since my transaction didn't get rolled back, My data is getting inconsistent.